# M2EPro 6.2.x description template

Tags: magento-1.9, m2e

I need to be able to post my ebay listings with a custom template that includes style changes and my returns policy etc, but i cant find where to add the description template in m2epro 6.2.1, it is mentioned in earlier versions of m2epro (5.x) but i cant find anything re: 6.x versions

can someone help!! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my answer - what i was looking for was the listing policy which is located in "Sell on Ebay > Configuration > Policies" and then "Add Policy > Description" and then choosing "Custom description" from the drop down.